# IndexError selecting from pandas dataframe with unique values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Using the following code, I'm trying to identify all the unique values of client names from one consolidated file and split the information into separate, individual files using those values.

```
split_clients = Prod_Imp_with_CountandPrice["Company_Name"].unique()
print(split_clients)

for value in split_clients:
    Prod_Upload = split_clients[split_clients["Company_Name"] == value]
    output_filename1 = str(value)+"_Product_Upload.xlsx"
    Prod_Upload.to_excel('FILEPATH'+output_filename1, index=0)
```

On the line `Prod_Upload = split_clients[split_clients["Company_Name"] == value]`, I'm getting the following error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-725346118bb5> in <module>
      5 
      6 for value in split_clients:
----> 7     Prod_Upload = split_clients[split_clients["Company_Name"] == value]
      8     output_filename1 = str(value)+"_Product_Upload.xlsx"
      9     Prod_Upload.to_excel('FILEPATH'+output_filename1, index=0)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

How may I change the code to get rid of this error?

Comment: assuming `Prod_Imp_withCointandPrice` is a pandas dataframe, `split_clients` will be a numpy array. So `split_clients["Company_Name"]` doesn't make sense. I think you meant to slice the whole dataframe, not just split_clients?

Comment: See the pandas docs on [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado: Hey, so what I was trying to do was capture the unique values in an array and then use that array to run the loop. Can you suggest the right way to do that please?

Comment: Yep - you can loop over the values in split clients, but use the values to slice the elements of the dataframe. Replace split_clients with Prod_Imp_with_CountandPrice in line 7.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thank you so much for the help!